# Undecidability: writing a symbol on Turing Machine's tape

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, undecidability

I wonder to know if given a Machine $M$, a string $x$ and a symbol $\phi$, would $M$ ever write $\phi$ ?

**My approach**

Maybe i can show if the problem is undecidable by contradiction using $M$ to prove $\operatorname{HALTING PROBLEM}$, but i'm stuck here. Any hints ?

Answer (score 2):

First take a Arbitrary Turing Machine M and modify it so that on stopping state it will first write a new symbol $\phi$ that it won't write at any other time.

If you can decide that Machine M' will write that symbol then you can decide whether machine M halted.

Comment: How i can decide if $M_1$ will write that symbol?

Comment: @Jack you can't without also being able to solve Halting, that's the point of my post.

Comment: So I can do iff I can solve Halting Problem. But HP is not decidable. Here's the contradiction, therefore the problem P is not decidable. Right?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Modify $M$ so it writes $\phi$ if and only if it halts.

> Choose $\phi$ so it's not in the original $M$'s alphabet.